# Instantiating at random based on word

Tags: c++, arrays, unity-game-engine, random, hashmap

I have a word = "CAT"
I have 26 alphabet prefabs A - Z - prefab array
I want to instantiate 6 prefabs from the prefab at random
so B,L,T,C,A,T - in any random order
but I need it to include the letters that makeup the word cat

My first thought was to use a dictionary/hashmap to map the word cat to the position in the array i.e C = [2] A = [0] T[]
but the hashmap/dictionary only takes a key value pair but I am providing it with more than one value the 3 letters needed

This is being programmed in unity so my prefabs are already in the letters array its just getting them to include my spelling.

```
public GameObject[] letters;
void Start() {

    int x;

    /* for loop execution */
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x = x + 1)
    {

        CreateCubes();
    }
}

     public void CreateCubes()
    {

        GameObject obj = Instantiate(letters[Random.Range(0, 26)]);
        obj.transform.position = new Vector3(

     );
```

Comment: If you're using Unity, are you actually writing code in C++, or is it C#?

Comment: Actually, I think the most pressing issue here is neither the language tag, nor the difficulty of reading your question, but the fact that you haven't provided any code. Stack Overflow is here to help you fix your code, not to write it for you.

Comment: we can help, but show us how you access your prefabs, you mention an array, can you paste it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have all prefabs in a `GameObject[]` array you could use this to auto-populate a dictionary

```c#
public GameObject[] prefabs = new GameObject[26];

private Dictionary<char, GameObject> CharToPrefab = new Dictionary<char, GameObject>(26);

private void Start()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        // add 0 to 26 to the start character A
        // results in A-Z
        CharToPrefab[(char)('A' + i)] = prefabs[i];
    }
}
```

Than you can access a certain prefab by calling

```c#
CharToPrefab[character];
```

For generating the instances (simplest version without taking any doubles into account) you could do e.g.

```c#
public void RandomLetters(string word)
{
    // 1. spawn the minimum required letters to build the word
    foreach (var letter in word)
    {
        var obj = Instantiate(CharToPrefab[letter]);
        // maybe use obj for something e.g. shuffel all instantiated objects positions
    }

    // 2. fill the rest with random letters
    // assuming always same amount as word letters
    var rand = new System.Random();
    foreach (var letter in word)
    {
        // pics a number from 0 to 26
        // and adds it to the char -> results in A-Z
        var randomChar = (char)('A' + rand.Next(0, 27));
        var obj = Instantiate(CharToPrefab[randomChar]);
        // maybe use obj for something e.g. shuffel all instantiated objects positions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this & see how it goes